# I'm trying to Use AppLoading to render home screen components but cant get the splash screen to stay until everything is loaded

Tags: react-hooks, react-native, react-native-ios, splash-screen

After optimising my images iv realised that I still need more time for my components to load. They are card like components with images.

I have 2 components to load one is in a flatList, the other just a basic card like component each component contains images. I have been trying in vain to get this to work and have to ask if anyone has a good solution. Here's what I have so far.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";

import Header from "./components/Header";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";

const fetchHomeScreen = () => {
  return HomeScreen.loadAsync({
    HomeScreen: require("./screens/HomeScreen"),
    Header: require("./components/Header"),
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const [HomeScreenLoaded, setHomeScreenLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (!HomeScreenLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchHomeScreen}
        onFinish={() => setHomeScreenLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Header title="Your Beast Log" />
      <HomeScreen />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#3E3636",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using expo status bar ?? then try these;
import splash screen

```
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
```

add this to the top of main function

```
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()
export default function App() {....}
```

then add this to your screen where you hide the splash screen

```
const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
    if(appIsready) {
        (async () => {
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        })()
    }
},[appIsReady])

async function prepare() {
  try {
    await fetchHomeScreen;
    //OR
    await HomeScreen.loadAsync({
              HomeScreen: require("./screens/HomeScreen"),
              Header: require("./components/Header"),
          });
  } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
  } finally {
    // Tell the application to render
    setAppIsReady(true);
  }
}
```